# Most efficient way of having two different layouts in Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

im working on a chat layout and i need TWO "different" layouts for send & received messages. The 2 layouts are almost the same, so it could be posible to have just one and dynamically change its background and some of its gravity/margin/padding properties.

After working with RecyclerView i have a doubt about efficiency. To achieve my goal i see two approaches:

1. Use 1 view and modify it programatically inside onBindViewHolder()
2. Use 2 view types.
3. ¿Any more efficient way?

After searching a bit, i am not sure what is the best and most efficient approach here, so some expert advise would be nice. Thank you.

PD: Backgrounds are 9patch images and in scenario 1, im loading them using getResources() and setBackground(). Scroll feels a bit slow on old devices.

Comment: did you have any performance issues w/ RecyclerView before? if not, why to worry?

Comment: Scroll feels a bit slow on old devices. PD: Backgrounds are 9patch images, im not sure how slow is setting them dynamically, thats why im asking!

Comment: so first provide only views with no data and see how it works, if no performance issues found add your data and again see how it works, with that 2 simple steps you will find what slows down your app

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is actually built into RecyclerView. You will notice that the method signature for `createViewHolder` is `createViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)`. The `viewType` is in fact what you need. To do this, you override `getItemViewType` so that depending on the position, it returns a different integer for sent or received messages. This will allow you to, in `createViewHolder` create a simple switch statement to pick the appropriate view type.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(listOfMessages.get(position).isSentMessage())
           return 1;
        else
           return 2;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        if(viewType == 1)
            //inflate sent message layout
        else if(viewType == 2)
            //inflate received message layout.
}
```

Comment: i believe OP knows that: see his approach #2 `Use 2 view types.`

Comment: Yes i already know that, my question is if this is the correct/efficient way of doing this! Thanks for the code anyways.

Comment: It is in fact the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, measure and see if it is critical session worth effort.

After that, it is generally a good practice to merge types unless it is costly to swap them. Just changing the background should be fine. Framework will mutate an already cached drawable id but I'm not sure how cheap it will be depending on your drawable. If it turns out to be expensive, you can recycle those background drawables manually.